# FIWARE: How to integrate the new application

Tags: cloud, fiware, fiware-poi

Let's say there is a web service that makes some calculations and returns some data. This web service should use some [Generic Enablers of FIWARE](http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers), for instance GIS Data Provider and POI Data Provider.

How to integrate such web service into the FIWARE cloud platform? Is there any guidance about it? I'm the beginner in this topic and it's is not clear how my tool should connect all the required Generic Enablers. Once connected, should I upload all this staff to some predefined server or can I use any virtual server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your own server the FIWARE catalog contains links to installations instructions for each GE. In the FILAB cloud portal you can also you use the ready images to launch GE's directly without manual installation. For some of the GE's there is also a ready running instance available in the FILAB Cloud servers for initial trialing, e.g. for POI such a demo service can be found here: http://poi.webhop.org/.

Answer (score 0):

## Integrating to a POI Server - *Some additional details*

Currently there are not many public and maintained POI servers, so, you may need to install your own POI server for your production system. You can install your POI server to the hosting service that suits best to your business, that may be Fiware Cloud or something else, and upload you data there.

### Hosting a POI Server at Fiware Cloud

You may use Fiware Cloud Portal https://cloud.lab.fiware.org/ to host experimental POI server. Press "Sign up" link there, if you need a new account. (Currently this does not seem to work: "Follow instructions on http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/poi-data-provider/creating-instances") Launch a Ubuntu 14.04 instance and install the POI Data provider as explained in the next section:

### Hosting a POI Server at Other Linux Style Environment

For Ubuntu Server 14.04., to install the POI server, follow the instructions in http://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/poi-data-provider/documentation -> "POI Data Provider - Installation and Administration Guide", or directly http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide

### Integrating Your Service to the POI Server

Overview of the POI system can be found at http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.OpenSpecification.MiWi.POIDataProvider

To integrate your service to the POI server you need information found in the API documentation. The API documentation can be found at http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_Open_API_Specification